# How to type a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: matrices

How to type the following bivariate normal distribution? I am only able to type each independent matrix. But I can't connect them with a symbol"~"

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\mu  \\
\nu 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `\sim` help?

Comment: It works. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approving totally the proposal of @Marian G. I put my MWE that produces the same your figure.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v
\end{pmatrix}\sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho\sigma \\
\rho\sigma & \sigma^2
\end{pmatrix}\right).
\]
\end{document}
```